# If a Button is selected in one activity in another activity the check box should get tick mark

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox

I have two activities one of the activity there is a  button called accept ,if user press the accept  button it comes back to the main activity and in the main activity the check box should be tick in kotlin

Comment: pass data to second activty

Comment: There are various ways to accomplish that. For example, the activity with the button could call `setResult` before `finish` when the button is pressed, and the main activity could check the result by overriding `onActivityResult` (requires starting the second activity with `startActivityForResult`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to start the next activity (Activity having ACCEPT button) via startActivityForResult. So on click of ACCEPT button, You will need to pass intent to MainActivity with appropriate value inside intent.

Refer this for more details : [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)